# Is x:Array supported on Windows Phone 7

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to use array in ConverterParameter in binding as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/permanenttan/archive/2009/06/19/array-as-a-wpf-converterparameter.aspx), but I get the following error:

```
The type 'x:Array' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

Is this extension supported on WP7? Or even better - is there a comprehensive list of differences between "desktop" and WP7 versions of XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up the differences between WPF and Silverlight (for example [this one](http://unknownerror.net/2011-06/34138-list-similarities-and-differences-between-wpf-silverlight-recommended.html)). WP7 7.0 is Silverlight 3.0 with some goodies when 7.5 is Silverlight 4.0.

If I were you I wouldn't write my own converter (PDC session - it could have performance issues).

What are you trying to do?

EDIT: x:Array is not supported :P

Comment: Would +1 this answer if it also included the categoric "No x:Array is not supported" which is the primary question asked.

Comment: @lukas the url you used in the answer does not work anymore. I get a domain place holder now.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about windows phone 7 developement, but if `x:Array` is not supported then similar type of structure that you can refer explicitly is `ArrayList` ...

```
 <Window ...
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace;assembly=SomeProject"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
         xmlns:coll="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
         ...>
    <Window.Resources>
       <local:MyAppenderConverter x:Key="MyAppenderConverter"/>
       <coll:ArrayList x:Key="MyArrayList">
           <sys:String>Hello</sys:String>
           <sys:String>World</sys:String>
       </coll:ArrayList>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                  Converter="{StaticResource MyAppenderConverter}"
                  ConverterParameter="{StaticResource MyArrayList}"/>
    </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Let me know if this helps.